# CSS: Make divs top positioned relating to its top div bottom line (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

I have difficulties to explain what I need so I include this image for that. I need to get something like this

[image]

I know I can get this with plugins. I wonder if this is possible ONLY with css (also for IE8)

Comment: Google the term "Masonry". Last time I tried with pure CSS it didn't go well, though.

Comment: How specific is positioning? Do you want the sections to populate vertically or horizontally.

Comment: @Bill :((( I found that already, didn't want to use plugin.Btw thanks.

Comment: @88 MPG I want it to be positioned horizontally, separately from each other. With vertical positioning will be easy

Comment: @BillCriswell's answer is correct and I would add that Isotope is a great choice too. You can't do this with pure css unless this was read vertically.

Comment: The content will be populated dynamically? Will it have infinite scroll and loading additional elements via ajax? How your html structure looks like? Will it be responsive?

Comment: @Bojan, all of this data should be loaded dynamically and be responsive, also users can add new item clicking on "load more" button. Structure and loading way is depended from the method I will use to get this.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a solution for your answer.

Check this link:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/nuauntmo

```css
p { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.third {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 30%;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.grid1 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.grid2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #3434ff;
}

.grid3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #3434ff;
}

.grid4 {
  height: 350px;
  background: #ff0f00;
}

.grid5 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.grid6 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #3434ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="third">
    <div class="grid grid1">
      <p>Grid 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid2">
      <p>Grid 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
   <div class="grid grid3">
      <p>Grid 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid4">
      <p>Grid 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <div class="grid grid5">
      <p>Grid 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid6">
      <p>Grid 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/hww0cn2c this link gives 404 error.
Also I need this not to be grouped vertically. Btw Thanks!

Comment: Check again, i changed link thats why you noticed the error 404.

Now it should be up again.

The divs are grouped vertically. If you check the structure of the html code you will notice that the div with the class "third" groups vertically the inner elements.

Comment: thanks for answer, but vertical groups will complicate dynamic loading functionality, so I've choosed Masonry plugin